# assign module to K2 category page

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, k2, joomla3.4

I want to assign some modules into category page of K2. In another words I want to change the K2 category page's module with the one which I want. How am I suppose to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your project find out this file path
components\com_k2\templates\default\category.php
then place the code with your module name

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
// this is where you want to load your module position
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('header'); 
foreach($modules as $module)
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
```

Note: please make the module visible for all page (show all pages)

Comment: I am new in this, please tell me what the line 2 means I mean what should I put there, then which line should I put this code in?